# Magento 2: Add Hyper link to store copyright text

Tags: magento2, copyright

Anybody have an idea, about how to add hyperlink text to store copy right text.

eg: Powered & Digital Marketing By [hyper link] Technologies.

Answer (score 0):

Install this simple extension this path `magento 2 root/app/code/` :-

**https://github.com/nadeem0035/allow-html-tags**

And after installation run this command :-

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento c:c
php bin/magento c:f
```

2. Go to your admin panel and **Content->configuration->theme edit->Footer section again-> now it will allowed you to add html tags**

[image]

After run `php bin/magento c:f`

**check output**
[image]

Hope this help you

Thanks ...

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your quick respond. I have resolved it by adding html tags with copyright text.

```
Powerd By <a href="" >link text </a>
```